# Over-parameterization in Bayesian Hierarchical Model

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, interaction, hierarchical-bayesian, model-comparison

Can someone explain the influence of adding parameters to a Bayesian model?

I have read from Kruschke that Bayesian analysis 'accounts' for model complexity by way of multiple priors, however I don't understand what this term implies in terms of the parameter estimates.

For instance, I have parameter of interest, but also a few other parameters that I am trying to control for but that are not of theoretical interest per se. What would be effect of adding an interaction term between one of these block parameters and the parameter of interest on the estimate of the parameter of interest if (i) the interaction term is centered at zero or (ii) the interaction matters a lot.

Comment: Welcome to our site! There's no need here to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it 
might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site 
([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future 
readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.
The best way to thank the person who gives you the most helpful answer to your question is to "accept" it with the green tick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Important to note first: Bayesian inference does NOT automatically guard against overfitting. Adding additional variables will pretty much result in the same problems as in an non-Bayesian analysis.
2. However, Bayesian model selection / model weights via marginal likelihood / Bayes factor CAN effectively include a penalty of model complexity, depending on how parameter priors are specified (generally, the wider the priors are, the more penalty of complexity - you can see this directly in the definition of the marginal likelihood).
3. Moreover, it is possible to regularize regression problems, similar to lasso or ridge regression, in a hierarchical model (e.g. Park, T. & Casella, G. (2008) The Bayesian Lasso. J. Am. Stat. Assoc., 103, 681-686.). I would think that the quote refers to this, or simply to the idea of random effect structures, which impose a shrinkage to the random effect estimates.